# In redmine how do I Send notification with new issue id to sender of email that created the issue

Tags: notifications, email, redmine, redmine-plugins

I have Redmine set to create issues on incoming email - unkown_user=create. I would like to send the user an email confirming receipt of the issue with the new issue id. Is there a way to do this?

On a related note, while the user is getting created in Redmine the new user does not get any notification on the account creation.

Notification to existing users work.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no confirmations on incoming emails. I am working on this for a client and we will be adding it to [ChiliProject](https://www.chiliproject.org) once it's ready (few minor bugs left). If you wanted to look at the code, I have it in a branch on [github](https://github.com/edavis10/redmine_for_clients/tree/LSS-4794-confirmation-email-from-mail-handler).

To answer your second question, the MailHandler doesn't notify new users when they are created. It would be a simple feature to add since the mailer code is already done. Basically add a `Mailer.deliver_account_information()`.

Comment: It looks like mail_handler.rb has the code to deliver account info but does not work
when 'create'
        @user = MailHandler.create_user_from_email(email)
        if @user
          logger.info "MailHandler: [#{@user.login}] account created" if logger && logger.info
          Mailer.deliver_account_information(@user, @user.password)
        else
          logger.error "MailHandler: could not create account for [#{sender_email}]" if logger && logger.error
          return false
        end

Comment: Looks like your change is to email users if the incoming email is missing some required attributes. I tried to use Mailer.deliver_issue_add(issue) in mail_handler.rb's receive_issue right above logger.info. Does not seem to work. Please help

Comment: Try this code. It should be changed in the `create_user_from_email` method and not at the top. https://gist.github.com/893492